# pandas MovingOLS doesn't support NA values?

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the `pandas.ols` function from version 0.7.3. I am interested in doing a moving regression, such as:

```
model = pandas.ols(y = realizedData, x = pastData, intercept = 0, window_type="rolling", window = 80, min_periods = 80)
```

The inputs contain data for about 600 dates, of which 15 are NA values.  But the output only contains regression results for about 120 dates.  The issue is that whenever the window contains even one NA value, there is no output for that window.  The problem disappears if I change window_type to `expanding` and I get about 500 output points as expected, but I don't want to do an expanding regression.

Can you tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting `min_periods` to be less than the window size (like 70, say). That means the minimum number of non-NA periods-- whenever you have an NA in the window the result will be NA.