# Pandas ols MovingOLS

Tags: python, pandas, regression, missing-data

I have a question relative to the property of pd.stats.ols.MovingOLS. When I try to do moving window OLS regression with the MovingOLS function, I do not have my expected result. I set a `min_periods = 2` and a `window = 4` for this function.

I realize that the OLS does not do the job when the window-end element is missing, even though the total number of observations satisfies the minimum observation requirement.

For example, in the following data, I should have results at position 2 and 5. But since the last element in these windows are nan, the regression gives no result. But the total numbers in the windows exceed the minimum number requirement. Do you know how to fix it?

```
a = pd.Series([1,2,3,2,np.NaN,np.NaN,5,2,np.NaN,4.5,3.2,3,np.NaN,8])
b = pd.Series([1,-2,np.NaN,2,5,2.5,5,2,np.NaN,4.5,np.NaN,2,np.NaN,])

pd.stats.ols.MovingOLS(y=b, x=a, window_type='rolling', window=4,
                       min_periods=2, intercept=False).beta
```

[image: Data]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas MovingOLS doesn't support NA values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197690/pandas-movingols-doesnt-support-na-values)

Comment: I understand the set up with min_periods. The question here is more: no matter what min_periods we put, in case the last element of the window is NaN, the result will always give NaN. OLS will not do the regression in this case.

Comment: What version of pandas are you using, I am not able to find that function in the documentation of 19.1

Comment: This is the old version and is deprecated. They move to statemodel OLS. But the statsmodel OLS does not provide rolling regression feature